# Is using the plural, in this sentence, the default choice?

Tags: word-choice, plural

I hear this sentence in the Italian version of *Law & Order: Special Victims Unit*. I understand I should take it with a little of *cum grano salis*, and that trying to understand why the plural was used could make little sense, as the translation could have been chosen to be closer to the original sentence in American.

A person, speaking also for other two people, said:

> Non vogliamo gli avvocati. Abbiamo deciso di confessare.

In English, the literal translation would be the following. (It's probably not what an American would say.)

> We don't want the lawyers. We decided to confess.

I would expect the first sentence to be *Non vogliamo l'avvocato.* I would not take that to mean there will be a single lawyer representing all three, even if I would not exclude that possibility.

Is using the plural in that sentence the default choice for writing it? Does using the singular give to the sentence a slightly different meaning?

Comment: My impression is that “gli avvocati” is used in a general sense. “We don’t want lawyers, we want to confess” the sense being “any lawyer”.

Comment: In that case, I would say _Non vogliamo avvocati._ which would be similar to _We don't want lawyers._

Comment: In Italian you would use the article, while you don’t in English, the meaning is the same.

Comment: @Hachi, No, in Italian the article isn't used, when the word is generically referring to somebody: _non vogliamo asini in classe_, _non vogliamo incapaci nella nostra squadra_, _non vogliamo tecnici al governo_.

Comment: I all the above examples, the articles would be grammatical. “Non vogliamo i tecnici al governo”. While it would not be in English.

Comment: Neither is ungrammatical, but the meaning is different.

Comment: Also, in English, _I have books in my locker_ and _I have the books in my locker_ are both grammatically correct. They have a slightly different meaning, though.

Comment: I don’t understand what your point is with respect to your question.

Comment: My point is that _non vogliamo gli avvocati_ and _non vogliamo avvocati_ have different meanings. The question is about _non vogliamo gli avvocati_. I am not questioning the grammaticallity of those sentences, contrary to the comment you posted.

Comment: To me the meaning is the same in Italian, while the use of the article in English implies a different meaning.

Comment: “Non volgiamo i tecnici al governo” oppure  “non vogliamo tecnici al governo.”

Comment: _non vogliamo gli asini in classe_ doesn't have exactly the same meaning _non vogliamo asini in classe_ has. The first would be used to speak of people in the classroom, while the last could be used to mean _non ci sono asini in classe, ma se ci fossero, non li vorremmo_ or to speak of people in the classroom "as if" they weren't in the classroom.

Comment: I see no real difference between *non vogliamo l'avvocato/avvocati/gli avvocati*. But it's a specific feature of *avvocato*, not a general feature of Italian.

Comment: Sorry @kiamlaluno but I disagree.

Comment: @egreg No, it's not a specific feature of _avvocato_. There are similar phrases where _avvocato_ isn't involved: _non vogliamo i truccatori_, _non vogliamo acconciatori_. What is specific of the sentence I wrote is that it's usually expected that a single lawyer doesn't represent three people accused of the same chrime.

Comment: @kiamlaluno *Nessuno di noi vuole l'avvocato* (which is more common than *un avvocato*) becomes *non vogliamo l'avvocato*. Interpreting this as *we don't want a single lawyer to represent all three of us* would be quite contrived..

Comment: @egreg It would be, indeed, but I wouldn't interpret _nessuno di noi vuole l'avvocato_ in that way. I interpret _non vogliamo l'avvocato_ as _each of us doesn't want a lawyer for him/herself_. That's why I am asking if using the plural (_avvocati_) is the default in those cases.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's not the “default”. As I said, the three ways are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default.

I'd interpret *Non vogliamo l'avvocato* as *none of us wants a lawyer*. A single lawyer for the group or one for each convicted is completely irrelevant, given the second clause “we want to confess”.

My impression is that the singular would be more idiomatic and more natural in fast speech. The form *Non vogliamo gli avvocati* would convey the same idea and I feel it less natural, but it could depend on the context.

It wouldn't be different with a positive declaration: *Vogliamo l'avvocato* might be interpreted either as *we want a lawyer to assist us* or *each one of us wants a lawyer*. The context would clear things up, but it could well be *Vogliamo gli avvocati* to strengthen the idea that they want distinct lawyers.

Answer (score -1):

No it's not the default choice. You should say `"Non vogliamo l'avvocato"` if you hired only one lawyer, `"Non vogliamo gli avvocati"` if you hired more than one. Honestly to me they should have adapted to `"Non vogliamo nessun avvocato"`, to express the fact that they don't need any lawyer.